# Flutter: Use a parameter inside a widget call (Icon)

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am new to flutter. I have extracted a widget in order to create signin-buttons.
I want to pass a parameter which specifies the icon which should be used, however I cannot add my parameter inside the method call of the Icon widget. How can this be managed?

The error appears inside the Icon-Widget.
Code:

```
  class LoginButtonIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final String iconName;

  const LoginButtonIcon({Key key, @required this.iconName}) : super(key: key);
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => "Pressed",
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.iconName,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 15,
            ),
            Text("RaisedButton",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14)),
          ],
        ),
        color: Colors.black54);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***iconName*** type should not be ***String***, it should be ***IconData*** and you should pass full icon like this ***Icons.add***

Answer (score 2):

you are on the right way. now declare a function which return a Icon-Widget. In the function use a switch-case, to return a different Icon depending on the String which is delivered as parameter.

```
Icon _getCorrectIcon() {
    switch (iconName) {
      case 'name-a':
        return Icon(Icons.a);
      case 'name-b':
        return Icon(Icons.b);
      case 'name-c':
        return Icon(Icons.c);
      default:
        return Icon(Icons.a);
    }
  }
```

replace your Row to:

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        _getCorrectIcon(),
        SizedBox(
          width: 15,
        ),
        Text("RaisedButton",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14)),
      ],
    ),
```